# AC not working on a 2005 Chevy Sonic

Tags: chevrolet, ac, compressor, sonic

I took my 2015 Chevy Sonic to the dealer because my air conditioner wasn't working. I've had a million problems with this car but it's been under warranty till now. Theyve even replaced the motor. Or so they say. But they told me it was the compressor and it would cost 600$ and they didn't even know if that would fix it. I've been looking online at some things but was just wondering if the fan kicks on when I turn the air conditioner on does that mean the compressor is working? Is there a way to tell if it's working or not? Also it is still slowly leaking antifreeze and has overheated several times.

Comment: Go to a good local mechanic - that dealer may not be the "best" in the area...

Comment: In fact now it is out of warranty, avoid the dealer unless there is no alternative. While I am not paying they can make as many guesses as it takes to stumble upon the solution, but once I have to pay, I will go to someone who can make a correct diagnosis. If the compressor is working, you will be able to feel a cold pipe.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Sorry you're having so many issues with your Sonic. I think if the compressor is spinning without issue, it's working, or at least compressing. If something goes wrong, it usually will seize up. The fan coming on is a good sign, but not foolproof. You should be able to see the compressor turning over when the A/C is turned on.

Comment: A qualified service technician should be able to definitively identify a bad compressor.  Take it to a respected local shop that does automotive A/C work.  There are many much less expensive things that prevent A/C from working than the compressor which are also a lot more likely.

Comment: It would be unusual for the compressor to fail after 6 years (I've had many original compressors go for over 20 years). Any shop with basic refrigeration equipment like a manifold set will be able to do a proper diagnosis.